# authorization - how to check for user permissions in web app?

Tags: mysql, web-applications, authorization

I have a simple straightforward implementation of authorization. Well, I only think I do and I want to make sure this is the right approach.

In my database I have tables like: `users`, `roles`, `user_role`, `permissions`, `role_permission` and `user_permission`.

When I create a user, I am of course giving him a role, and this role has already some permissions. I want to check for the permissions not for the role here obviously, but I am curious about if I should check for these permissions only from the `role_permission` table or checking for `user_permission` which is, I think, much more flexible because the user can have some permissions given by default from the `role_permission` table and then maybe add, remove, permission later by an administrator.

I think that the second approach is better, I want to ask if I am right, is this the way it should be done? I am not sure about copying the contents of the `user_permission` table into the `user_permissions` table. Maybe I should do this another way, I think this step is a kinda weird one.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, you are reinventing the wheel so you should look at the existing solutions to do this in whatever technologies you are using. Getting security right is hard so where possible you should make use of what specialists in the field have provided.

Having said that personally I would not allow individual permissions separate from the group ones. If you do that and have more than a few users it becomes an administrative nightmare. Imagine the scenario where there is a critical bug found in a section of the software and it is imperative no-one uses it. You go in and remove that permission from all the roles...job done right? But no, someone was granted the role separately and can still access it. You also have all the extra code and complexity to maintain to allow the separate roles.

That's just one example, but hopefully it shows some of the complications you are starting to allow.

With having multiple roles per user there is nothing that you can do with individual permissions that you can't do by defining and using appropriate roles.

Incidentally if you are caching the users permissions remember that you will need to update that cache both when the user's role changes and when the role's permissions change.

Comment: Thank you for a quick and detailed answer, thats a good set of reasons i should stick to, I didnt think of that. It is actually my first big project and it is (i hope) nearly finished, I want to check for the permissions in needed controller methods. I am using codeigniter and there was no authorization that I was aware of. I inspired myself from the a3m authorization for codeigniter [this-link-a3m](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/A3M-Account-Authentication-and-Authorization)

Comment: So then it probably doesnt matter whether I check for the permission or the role itself does it?

Answer (score 0):

Every Linux/Unix support both personal permissions as well as group ones.
So this is nice feature to support and most of the users will actually expect it by default to be available.

Otherwise @Tim B is right - no need to reinvent the wheel. Every framework nowadays has user module/extension that support permissions and roles.

If for some reason you want to implement it yourself, then the steps should look like:

1. Get the list of user personal permissions
2. Get the list of user permissions granted by the role
3. Add (concatenate) both sets and use the result as a list of the current user permissions

If there is a cache, then of course each change in the role or individual permissions should invalidate the already cached permissions for the user.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Antoan Milkov and Tim B: no need to reinvent the wheel.

Depending on the framework you are using, there are plenty of viable solutions. Here are a few:

- Java: use Spring Security (it's not the only option)
- .NET: use Microsoft's claims-based authentication and authorization
- Ruby: use CanCan
- Python: use Flask-Auth
- and many more...

If you want to learn more about the theory behind authorization (and more broadly access control), read up on role-based access control and attribute-based access control both of which are very well documented at NIST:

- RBAC: http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/SNS/rbac/
- ABAC: http://csrc.nist.gov/projects/abac/

Lastly, if you want a standards-based approach, consider XACML, the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language which implements ABAC and gives you a policy-based approach to authorization.

- [OASIS XACML](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/xacml/%E2%80%8E)

Check wikipedia and YouTube for more information.